# Python Selenium Calling Hidden File Input

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, input, hidden

I am using selenium-python with chromedriver.

In a webpage,which is https://web.whatsapp.com/ ,I am trying to send a file with send_keys() to a file type input.

But the problem is,that input element is only visible in inspector when you drop a file on the webpage.If you close that menu(I don't mean native menu) element disappears from inspector.

How can I call that element if element is not displayed?

And element seems like this:

```
xpath='//*[@id="app"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/span[2]/span/div/div[2]/input'

<input type="file" accept="image/*,video/*" multiple="" style="display: none;">
```

I tried

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('parent_id').style.display='block';")

driver.execute_script("document.getElementByXpath('Xpath').sendKeys('file');")
```

But none of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wat to work with file input element then try to make it visible instead of it's parent element as below :

```
xpath = '//*[@id="app"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/span[2]/span/div/div[2]/input'

file = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)

file = driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display='block'; return arguments[0];", file)

file.seng_keys("file")
```

Comment: I got NoSuchElementException.Selenium couldn't find the element.

Comment: Element is cannot be seen until you drop a file on the webpage.

Comment: @.Saurabh thanks but still it can't find the element.